# How is the ternary operator evaluated in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

Regarding the ternary (`? :`) operator in JavaScript, I would like to know how it is evaluated by a typical browser's JavaScript interpreter:

Alternative A:

1. Evaluate the first operand.
2. If the result of the first operand is true, then evaluate and return the second operand.
3. Else, evaluate and return the third operand.

Alternative B:

1. All three operands are evaluated.
2. If the result of the first operand is true, return the result of the second operand.
3. Else, return the result of the third operand.

Alternative C:

Of course, if neither alternative A nor alternative B accurately describe how the ternary operator works, please explain me how it works.

Comment: The "alternative A": `(1)? functionOne(): functionTwo()`, if you put a simple alert message on both functions, only `functionOne` will display its message.

Comment: Oh, wow. Thanks. Post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: You could test this faster than someone replies.

Comment: I cannot test it on IE6, IE7 and IE8.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "alternative A":

```
(1)? functionOne(): functionTwo()
```

If you put a simple alert message on both functions, only functionOne will display its message.

```
function functionOne(){ 
   alert("one");
}
function functionTwo(){ 
   alert("two");
}
```

Answer (score 11):

[According to the specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.12) it works like in *Alternative A*:

> The production `ConditionalExpression : LogicalORExpression ? AssignmentExpression : AssignmentExpression` is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *`lref`* be the result of evaluating `LogicalORExpression`.
> 2. If `ToBoolean(GetValue(lref))` is **`true`**, then
>
>    - Let *`trueRef`* be the result of evaluating the first `AssignmentExpression`.
>    - Return `GetValue(trueRef)`.
> 3. Else
>
>    - Let *`falseRef`* be the result of evaluating the second `AssignmentExpression`.
>    - Return `GetValue(falseRef)`.

Answer (score 3):

The ternary operator evaluates lazily for several reasons.

1. It's inefficient to evaluate all the operands when you are only going to return either the if or the else
2. Doing lazy evaluation allows you to do things like `x != 0 ? 10 / x : 10;` If it evaluated everything at the same time you would get a divide by zero error if x were zero

Comment: Sorry, random correction: No division by zero error in JS. `1/0 === Infinity`

Answer (score 2):

Run this and find out:

```
function bool() {
    alert('bool');
    return false;
}

function a() {
    alert('a');
    return 'A';
}

function b() {
    alert('b');
    return 'B';
}

alert(bool() ? a() : b())
```