# How to pass a promise of an object on a ternary operator?

Tags: angularjs, promise, md-autocomplete

so I am implementing the Angular Material Design md-autocomplete directive on an AngularJS application. I want to send a promise to the control so if the query is not fully loaded, it won't throw an error; and also to see the loading bar in the control as a signal of "loading".

This is the error I get when the data hasn't finished loading:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined

This is how I am getting the data:

```
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: $rootScope.apiURL+'getAllCustomers/'+session,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function(response){
            if(response.ErrorMessage === null && response.Result !== null){
                mixpanel.track("Customers loaded for POS");
                self.customers = Object.keys(response.Result).map(function (key) {return response.Result[key]});
            }
        })
        .error(function(data){
            alert('Something went wrong. Please try again.');
            mixpanel.track("Error loading customers");
        });
```

Here is my html:

```
<md-autocomplete
        ng-disabled="ctrl.isDisabled"
        md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache"
        md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem"
        md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)"
        md-search-text="ctrl.searchText"
        md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)"
        md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)"
        md-item-text="item.Name"
        md-min-length="0"
        placeholder="Buscar Cliente">
    <md-item-template>
        <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.Name}}</span>
    </md-item-template>
    <md-not-found>
        No states matching "{{ctrl.searchText}}" were found.
        <a ng-click="ctrl.newCustomer(ctrl.searchText)">Create a new one!</a>
    </md-not-found>
</md-autocomplete>
```

These are the functions that process the queries:

```
function querySearch (query) {
    var results = query ? self.customers.filter( createFilterFor(query) ) : self.customers.slice(0, 50),
        deferred;
    return results;
}

function createFilterFor(query) {
    var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);
    return function filterFn(customer) {
        return (customer.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
    };
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is that `, deferred;` doing there, btw?

Comment: Try initialising `self.customers = []` before it will in the future get assigned the values from the promise

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code in question into a function:

```
function foo()
  {
  return foo.self.customers.slice(0, 50);
  }

foo.self = self;
```

Then change the statement to:

```
var results = query ? self.customers.filter( createFilterFor(query) ) : foo
```

And run the type checking in the template as ternary logic:

```
(typeof ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText) === "function") ? item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)() : item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)
```

**References**

- [How is the ternary operator evaluated in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097346/how-is-the-ternary-operator-evaluated-in-javascript)